# how to rollback a transaction which declared in batch from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

suppose i have a batch command like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @A1 int
SET @A1 = 10
EXEC sp_dosomethings @A1
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

In stored procedure "sp_dosomethings" i want to rollback the transation in some conditions like this:

```
IF (@A1 = 10) ROLLBACK
```

Now when i run this batch and place 10 in @A1, The transaction rolls back but an error raised and whole batch does not work!

```
ERROR: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

So how can i rollback the transaction from a stored procedure without causing SQL to raise any errors?!

Comment: . . I think it is better practice for the stored procedure `sp_dosomethings ` to return a status and let the calling decide whether to commit or rollback.  That is, keep the transaction semantics at one level.

Comment: No i don't think so! because this will not so simple when our procedures are nested and one of third or fourth procedure must rollback the transaction!!
do we must return status from one procedure to last and so to first batch to just rollback the transaction?! does it mean that there is no such thing in SQL SERVER?!

Comment: @GordonLinoff is definitely right here. You don't want to have a whole spaghetti of procedures where one may roll back while other continue merrily along. You can easily include a status parameter to any procedure that rolls up so any error both causes the transaction to roll back, and stops any other code from attempting to run. Even if you want to roll back in some lower level, the status is probably still a good idea.